# How to set DOCKER_SOCK variable to create container for service peer0.org3.example.com

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, peer

when i want to bring up the Org3 peer in hyperledger fabric network and run command :

docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose-org3.yaml up -d

I have some errors as fallow:

WARNING: The DOCKER_SOCK variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating peer0.org3.example.com ... error

ERROR: for peer0.org3.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer0.org3.example.com: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters

ERROR: for peer0.org3.example.com  Cannot create container for service peer0.org3.example.com: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

How I can solve that .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Was this issue resolved for you?

The error was because of following volume.

> - ${DOCKER_SOCK}:/host/var/run/docker.sock

The DOCKER_SOCK variable is not set in environment variables. So we need to prepare a .env file and set its value as

> DOCKER_SOCK=/var/run/docker.sock

After this executing the docker compose adds a container of fabric peer.

Comment: This doesn't solve my error. I am working in WSL ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because Docker Daemon is not connectable. It can either because daemon is down or you are not using the correct permission.

First, make sure daemon is active. [Here is the official doc](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/) to help you with that.

Second, try using "sudo" with docker-compompose:

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose-org3.yaml up -d
```

Also, there are a lot of answers regarding your question. You should do some googling or search in SO before posting.

Answer (score 0):

**/var/run/docker.sock** uses the docker daemon running on your host.

It is "possible" that the docker daemon is looking for the variables on the host rather than your guest shell.

Try one of the following:

1. Set the environment variables in the host (where the daemon is running)
2. Using using a [.env file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with---env-file) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on the same point, and simply exporting the DOCKER_SOCK variable with the following command worked for me and my peer got created for the org3.

```
export DOCKER_SOCK=/var/run/docker.sock
```

This is applicable for the latest version of **HyperLedger Fabric (2.5)** as well as of **Nov 2023**.